# Android Print from bluetooth only once

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth

We have a native android app which you can print invoice an waybill from it via bluetooth. i used default bluetooth adapter. When i hit print button from app, the bluetooth printer prints what i sent with no problem, but when i print again, printing text is corrupted. At the half of the document printer just stop and rewind the paper and print the left of the text that i sent. At that point i switch-off the printer and switch on again. then i press print from app. Again printer works fine in the first print. but when i print second copy, printer fail again. i couldnt understand whats going on. If i have a problem with the code or adapter that i used, i couldnt print any text message, but i have problem only in second copies.

Here is my code:

```
public BluetoothDevice FindPrinter() {
    BluetoothDevice currentDevice = null;

    try {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            throw new Exception("Bluetooth adaptorü bulunamadı");
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            Activity a = new Activity();
            a.startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                                 if(device.getName().equals(SharedPreferenceSettings.getPrinterPort(context))) {
                    currentDevice = device;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return currentDevice;
}
public void Print() 
{
    try {
        int current = 0;
        FormatData();
        int line = 0;

        Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
        mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, 1);
        mmSocket.connect();
        while (current < Data.length) {
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            int len = 256;
            if (current + 256 > Data.length) {
                len = Data.length - current;
            }
            byte[] temp = new byte[len];
            System.arraycopy(Data, current, temp, 0, len);
            int currentLine = CountLines(temp);
            line = line + currentLine;
            mmOutputStream.write(temp);
            current += len;
            Thread.sleep(1700);
        }
        mmOutputStream.close();
        if(mmSocket.isConnected())
            mmSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Print ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

EDIT:

i noticed something. if i run my app with debug and break points, it work flawlessly, but if i run it normally, sometimes printer skip first 256 bytes then print. still dont understand why the printer skip first 256 bytes sometimes.

Comment: Have you try to use 2 socket instrance . One for first text , second for copy?

Comment: must not need for the second socket. because after every print action i close and dispose the socket instance.

Comment: Have you try to write another bytes arrays length?                                         int len = 512;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution to my problem. it's a workaround but it works anyway. i add a Thread.sleep(100); after mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream(); line. after that it works fine. i don't know why but it works now.